# Accessing a member of struct in class, LinkedList Node

Tags: c++, class, struct, linked-list, nodes

So I am just starting out learning LinkedLists for C++. I know C+ has a library for them but I'm trying to focus on LinkedLists. An exercise I saw asks you to design a linked list class with 2 member functions and a default constructor: add, isMember, and the LinkedList() constructor. Add function adds a new node to the front of the list. isMember tests to see if the list contains a node with the value passed in to add.

My issue is, I am creating the ListNode *head in the struct, then I try to access it in the LinkedList constructor to set it to null, it is throwing me the error of "undeclared identifier". even if I set it to NULL in the struct it gives me the same error. The error goes away if I write "ListNode *head = NULL" in the constructor, but then my add method is still going crazy over the use of the "undeclared identifier" head.
Here's what I got so far:

LinkedList.h:

```
class LinkedList
{
protected:
    struct ListNode
    {
        double value;
        ListNode *next;
        ListNode(double value1, ListNode *next1 = NULL)
        {
            value = value1;
            next = next1;
        }
        ListNode *head;
    };
    // Public Interface
public:
    // Class Constructor(s)
    LinkedList();

    // Methods
    void add(double x);
    bool isMember(double x);

    // Private Class Members
private:
};
```

LinkedList.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "LinkedList.h"  // Class Definition file

// Class Default Constructor
LinkedList::LinkedList()
{
    head = NULL;
}

// Class Destructor
LinkedList::~LinkedList(void)
{
    ListNode *nodePtr;
    while (nodePtr != NULL)
    {
        ListNode *garbage = nodePtr;
        nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
        delete garbage;
    }
}

void LinkedList::add(double x)
{
    ListNode *nodePtr, *prevNodePtr;
    if (head == NULL || head->value >= x)
    {
        head = new ListNode(x, head);
    }
    else
    {
        nodePtr = head->next;

        while (nodePtr != NULL && nodePtr->value < x)
        {
            prevNodePtr = nodePtr;
            nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
        }

        prevNodePtr->next = new ListNode(x, nodePtr);
    }
}
bool LinkedList::isMember(double x)
{
        //tbd
}
```

Any clues as to why this is would be a huge help. Thanks!

Comment: `head` is a member of `ListNode`, not `LinkedList`. It really doesn't make sense for a `ListNode` to have a `head`.

Answer (score 1):

You declare ListNode structure, but you never declare anywhere any object which has ListNode type. So when you try to access `head` element from within your LinkedList method, it is indeed undeclared identifier, because LinkedList class doesn't have any element called `head`.

If you would have changed your LinkedList declaration like that:

```
class LinkedList
{
protected:
    struct ListNode
    {
        double value;
        ListNode *next;
        ListNode(double value1, ListNode *next1 = NULL)
        {
            value = value1;
            next = next1;
        }
        ListNode *head = NULL;
    } node; // actually instantiating ListNode element as part of LinkedList class
    // Public Interface
public:
    // Class Constructor(s)
    LinkedList();

    // Methods
    void add(double x);
    bool isMember(double x);

    // Private Class Members
private:
};
```

then you could have called the `head` element in this way:

```
LinkedList::LinkedList()
{
    node.head = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want head to be a member of LinkedList, not ListNode.

```
class LinkedList {
    class ListNode {
        double value;
        ListNode *next;
    };
    ListNode *head;
};
```